# Passing An Enum Type As An Generic Argument To a Function in swift 2.2 iOS

Tags: swift, generics, enums, generic-programming, swift2

I'm new to Swift iOS.. I'm trying to use enum type as input parameter to a function.. here is the

sample enum type:

```
public enum CFScreen {

public enum CFScreen_Newsfeed: Int {

    case Newsfeed_01 = 2100
    case Newsfeed_02 = 2101
    case Newsfeed_03 = 2102
    case Newsfeed_04 = 2103
    case Newsfeed_05 = 2104
    case Newsfeed_06 = 2105
    case Newsfeed_07 = 2106
    case Newsfeed_08 = 2107
}

public enum CFScreen_Groups: Int {

    case Create = 2200
    case GoBack = 2201
}
}
```

sample function using enum type as input parameter

```
func showCFScreenForEnumType(cFooter: CFScreen.CFScreen_Groups) {

    //Group Related
    switch cFooter {

    case .Create:
        print("Show Create Group")
        break

    case .GoBack:
        print("Show Go Back Screen")
        break
    }
}

func showCFScreenForEnumType(cFooter: CFScreen.CFScreen_Newsfeed) {

    //Group Related
    switch cFooter {

    case .Newsfeed_01:
        print("Show News 01")
        break

    case .Newsfeed_02:
        print("Show News 02")
        break

    case .Newsfeed_03:
        print("Show News 03")
        break

    case .Newsfeed_04:
        print("Show News 04")
        break

    case .Newsfeed_05:
        print("Show News 05")
        break

    case .Newsfeed_06:
        print("Show News 06")
        break

    case .Newsfeed_07:
        print("Show News 07")
        break

    case .Newsfeed_08:
        print("Show News 08")
        break
    }
}
```

Calling this functions as follows

```
let selCFScreenG = CFScreen.CFScreen_Groups.Create
    showCFScreenForEnumType(selCFScreenG)

let selCFScreenNF = CFScreen.CFScreen_Newsfeed.Newsfeed_01
    showCFScreenForEnumType(selCFScreenNF)
```

Taken Reference from link: http://www.codingexplorer.com/enumerations-swift/

My question is how i can write a function that will accepting enum types generically so that i can merge these below two functions into one

```
func showCFScreenForEnumType(cFooter: CFScreen.CFScreen_Groups)
func showCFScreenForEnumType(cFooter: CFScreen.CFScreen_Newsfeed)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a generic type constraint to some protocol, say `MyCFScreenEnums`, to which only the two enums in `CFScreen` conforms, and within the function that makes use of this (type constrained) generic, perform attempted type conversion to one of the two enums `CFScreen.CFScreen_Newsfeed`/`CFScreen.CFScreen_Newsfeed`. Since only these two conform to `MyCFScreenEnums`, one of these type conversions is guaranteed to be successful due to the type constraint of the generic (say `T`) to `MyCFScreenEnums`.

```
protocol MyCFScreenEnums { }
extension CFScreen.CFScreen_Newsfeed : MyCFScreenEnums {}
extension CFScreen.CFScreen_Groups : MyCFScreenEnums {}

func showCFScreenForEnumType<T: MyCFScreenEnums>(cFooter: T) {
    if let newsfeed = cFooter as? CFScreen.CFScreen_Newsfeed {
        switch newsfeed {
        case .Newsfeed_01: print("Show News 01")
        case .Newsfeed_02: print("Show News 02")
        case .Newsfeed_03: print("Show News 03")
        case .Newsfeed_04: print("Show News 04")
        case .Newsfeed_05: print("Show News 05")
        case .Newsfeed_06: print("Show News 06")
        case .Newsfeed_07: print("Show News 07")
        case .Newsfeed_08: print("Show News 08")
        }
    }
    else if let groups = cFooter as? CFScreen.CFScreen_Groups {
        switch groups {
        case .Create: print("Show Create Group")
        case .GoBack: print("Show Go Back Screen")
        }
    }
}

/* Example usage */
let foo = CFScreen.CFScreen_Newsfeed.Newsfeed_03
let bar = CFScreen.CFScreen_Groups.Create
showCFScreenForEnumType(foo) // "Show News 03"
showCFScreenForEnumType(bar) // "Show Create Group"
```